# Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - Cordova/CDVAppDelegate.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Im getting this error when I try to build with xcode 8.0. Doing build with `cordova build ios` works fine, but I need to be able to build with xcode.

Ive tried to remove/add platform and added `${OBJROOT}/UninstalledProducts/${PLATFORM_NAME}/include` to Header Search Paths Release/Debug.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Also i get the same issue in xcode 8.0

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. Hope your problem is solved.

```
cordova platform update ios
```